# calculating sum of values after combining results of multiple AJAX calls.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JS function which calculates the sum of all visible rows in a column in a table.
The way the values in the column is filled is by making multiple ajax calls (50 rows at a time).

I am trying to keep track of no of requests sent and when I receive all responses back  calculate the sum.

```
function onClickofCalculateButton() {
    var noOfRequestsSent = 0;
    var sum = 0;

    var sucCallback = function(response) {
        updateColumn(response, noOfRequestsSent, sum);
    };

    //Some logic to send requests 50 rows a time and I increment the value of noOfRequestsSent;
}
```

in my updateColumn function()

```
function updateColumn(response, noOfRequestsSent, sum) {
    noOfRequestsSent--;
    //Do some logic to retrieve value of each row and add it to sum
    if(noOfRequestsSent == 0) {
        alert(sum);
    }
}
```

However what is happening is the value of noOfRequestsSent is always equal to the actual number of requestssent even after subtracting it in updateColumn function. So it never reaches the condition where noOfRequestsSent == 0 and neither does the sum get added onto the previous value.

I guess I have to pass some object reference or something like pointers in C but I am unable to figure out how to do in JS.

Comment: First of all, you need to keep the number of requests in a variable outside of your function or it will just start over at 0 each time.

Comment: @Difster I want it that way. Each time the button is clicked, a new set of requests are sent.

Comment: Oh, I see. A lot of people get that wrong so I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this. Since you want to send variable as reference. In this way you can avoid global variables.

```
function onClickofCalculateButton() {
    var noOfRequests = {
                       sent:0
                       };
    var sum = 0;

    var sucCallback = function(response) {
        updateColumn(response, noOfRequests, sum);
    };

    //Some logic to send requests 50 rows a time and I increment the value of noOfRequestsSent;
}


function updateColumn(response, noOfRequestsSent, sum) {
    noOfRequests.sent--;
    //Do some logic to retrieve value of each row and add it to sum
    if(noOfRequests.sent == 0) {
        alert(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even making it global didnt work. the value doesnt reduce. Is there a way to avoid global values

Comment: are you sure that you are getting noOfRequestsSent  inside updateColumn function

Comment: Yes I am getting it. But even after reducing inside function, next time the fucntion is called, it doesnt have the reduced no.

Comment: Yes this works. So i guess I should add the sum as well in the json object?

Comment: indeed. if you need to avoid global @user1692342